# C# crop image trapezoid / polygon

Tags: c#, image, crop

I've got an image and I want to cut out a trapezoid from an image.

I've got 8 different coordinates like this (8 values to form a polygon with 4 Points)

```cs
pointA(222,222)
pointB(666,234)
pointC(678,235)
pointD(210,220)
```

I only found out how to crop images with `bitmap.Clone` like this

```
var x = pointA.x;
var y = pointA.y;
var height = pointD.y - pointA.y;
var width = pointB.x - pointA.x;
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imagepath);
var rect = new Rectangle(x, y, wight, height);
var newImage = image.Clone(rect, image.PixelFormat);
```

This will create a straight rectangle and the important parts of the sub-parts wich I want to cut out are disappearing.

So, how to cut out a trapezoid using c# and .net framework core from a console environment?

I want to cut out a trapezoid but I just figured out the better form to describe what I want is a polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=net-5.0) API. This has a [FillPolygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillpolygon?view=net-5.0) method that takes a list of points and a brush. To use the source bitmap you would use the [TextureBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.texturebrush?view=net-5.0). Put this together and you would end up with something like this:

```
    public Bitmap FillPolygon(Bitmap sourceBitmap, PointF[] polygonPoints)
    {
        var targetBitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256);
        using var g = Graphics.FromImage(targetBitmap);
        using var brush = new TextureBrush(sourceBitmap);
        g.FillPolygon(brush, polygonPoints);
        return targetBitmap;
    }
```

I think this should work from a windows console. There have historically been a few issues using some graphics APIs without a windows sessions, but I do not think this is a problem anymore.

For maximum compatibility you could always triangulate and [rasterize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139724/i-need-a-pixel-perfect-triangle-fill-algorithm-to-avoid-aliasing-artifacts) the trapezoid yourself and copy the selected pixels, but it would probably be significantly more work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - After I figured out "trapezoid" is a polygon too, I edited my question and also tried to implement the answer from this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954503/how-to-crop-a-polygonal-area-from-an-image-in-a-winform-picturebox but I get only black images

Comment: @derbjörn check that the target bitmap is large enough, and try drawing with for example `Brushes.White` to check that the drawing works. And some objects need to be disposed at the correct place for it to work correctly.

Comment: the target bitmap is large enough, I tried some approaches with the solution. But I need to tinker a little bit more to archive my solution. Meanwhile (and thanks again for this hint with Graphis-API) I figured out how to draw on the image - instead of "brushing" the zone out, I am able to draw a polygon on the image, using the "Pen" - This works - But even with your hint, all "transparent" or "black" images (resolution is "correct" but nothing is in the picture)

Comment: _I get only black images_ Please show the code you are using now! - _8 different points_ What does that mean???? The 4(!) points form more like a triangle than a trapez... - Also: How large is the source bitmap?

Comment: I was able to create a solution, thanks to @JonasH <3